# Django FloatField not auto selected value with Select widget in edit mode

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For example, I have a model field named `fraction`.

```
FRACTION_COUNT = (
    (0, '0'),
    (0.5, '0.5'),
    (1, '1'),
    (1.5, '1.5'),
    (2, '2'),
)

class MyModel(models.Model)
    test_fraction = models.FloatField(choices=FRACTION_COUNT, default=0.5)
```

Then in **ModelForm**, I tried this

```
self.fields['fraction'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=FRACTION_COUNT,
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        ),
        initial=self.instance.fraction if self.instance and self.instance.pk else 1
    )
```

The problem is that I save `fraction` as `1`.  Then in edit mode, the value `1` not auto-selected.

I tried some of StackOverflow answer but these won't work for me.

Do I miss something?

Comment: I would really advice against using `FloatField`s as a way to store `choices`, since floating points are prone to rounding errors. It is probably better to just use `1`.

Comment: I have only a few predefined float value, a user needs to select from them. Should I use CharField or any other instead of FloatField in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just define the choices like below should work:

```
FRACTION_COUNT = (
(0.0, '0'),
(0.5, '0.5'),
(1.0, '1'),
(1.5, '1.5'),
(2.0, '2'),
```

)